# Google Chrome find tab extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have dozens of tabs open in different windows. Sometimes, I can't find an oft visited tab such as GMail or Pandora. Is there any Chrome extension which would allow me to quickly search for a tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided to go with [Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl?hl=en-US), it looks like a Tree Style Tabs inspired extension from Firefox.

Comment: I like this one.  I believe I paid $15 or $20 for the extended features.  I'm not sure it's been updated in several years, though.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps its a bit more than you're looking for, but [vimium](http://vimium.github.com/) has this feature. Press `Shift + t` and a search bar appears in which you can type the name of the tab you want  and pres enter to jump to it.

Comment: vimium is great but it is indeed a lot more than i was looking for.

Comment: It unfortunate that you can't disable its features or remap the hotkeys.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried tab expose?

I use in conjuction with tab split and tab manager, they all perform small, different functions very well.

Comment: Can you give me some more detail about what each does?

Comment: tab expose is similar to TooManyTabs as it let's you navigate all your open tabs. The other two are useful if you use multiple windows at once: 
tab split created a new window with all the tabs at the right of the current one.
tab manager open a popup where you can move tab between all your open windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following extensions that offer tab searching capabilities, among various other useful features:

1. [Quick Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb):

   [image: 1]
2. [TooManyTabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toomanytabs-for-chrome/amigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp):

   [image: 2]

Comment: TooManyTabs looks like the right way to go but unfortunately there's an error when installing on Mac right now.