# Find an open tab in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

Added:  u1686_grawity helpfully notes that Ctrl-Shift-A achieves the same result, while being different from the access method that I was searching for. I'd still like top know why it comes and goes, but Ctrl-Shift-A does the job adequately.

---

I am trying to find how to enable the Google Chrome browser "search for open tab" feature.
When it is operating this feature is accessed via clicking a caron ( ' ̌ '  = inverted "^") symbol in the top right of each browser window. After this feature was implemented by Google it appeared unprompted, then a month + ago it vanished, then over periods of days to weeks it reappeared, then vanished again.

I suspect that I am toggling it in some manner but a good search of various settings and a web search on likely terms fails to provide an answer.

The Google "@tabs" feature provides similar (but not as good) functionality but I would like to be able to provide the method described above. Advice welcome.

---

I am running Google Chrome browser Version 120.0.6099.71on Windows 10 Pro 9045.3693.

[11 year old question](https://superuser.com/q/511997) wanting the same thing - that then was not directly available .

Comment: Does it show up again if you Ctrl-Shift-A?

Comment: @u1686_grawity  Thanks. No, but yes :-). That achieves (probably) identical functionality, but on the left of the screen and without the caron showing before/during/after. I still wonder what happened to the caron, but that will do nicely.

Comment: It's the shortcut shown within the popup that opens after pressing the caron. If the caron is gone and the shortcut opens something different, they probably moved it... again. Have you tried looking through `chrome://flags`?

Comment: I reopened Chrome, got the "Your browser got a brand new look" page, and the button is now to the left instead of the right, but it has not outright disappeared yet.